# 401 Unauthorized when publish to maven by gradle maven-publish plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory, publishing, maven-publish

> Could not PUT 'https://xxx.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized:

```
maven {
  name = "${infos.publish.snapshotId}"
  url = infos.publish.urls.snapshot
  credentials {
    username = "${passwords."${infos.publish.snapshotId}".username}"
    password = "${passwords."${infos.publish.snapshotId}".password}"
  }
  //authentication {
    //basic(BasicAuthentication)
    //digest(DigestAuthentication)
  //}
```

`username` and `password` are correct (using those to upload by `mvn clean deploy` was successful).

I have been tried `BasicAuthentication` and `DigestAuthentication` but they don't work.

I use gralde 6.8.3, plugin is `maven-publish`, maven server is Artifactory.

What's wrong?

### Close:

in properties file:

```
password="password"
```

means password is `"password"`

```
password=password
```

means password is `password`